# full join of 2 tables with common time

Tags: mysql, join

how am i able to join the 2 tables (A & B) below so that i can get the resulting table below

Please note that the query should join values that have the same time,

(i.e. `2014-11-29 9:58:23   6054    1` showing below in the result table)

**Table A**

```
ID      time                noise
76676   2014-11-29 09:55:24 6636
76677   2014-11-29 09:55:32 5256
76678   2014-11-29 09:55:42 5066
76679   2014-11-29 09:56:09 11560
76680   2014-11-29 09:56:22 5656
76681   2014-11-29 09:56:50 7031
76682   2014-11-29 09:56:56 5069
76683   2014-11-29 09:57:06 10088
76684   2014-11-29 09:57:23 5589
76685   2014-11-29 09:58:23 6054
```

**Table B**

```
ID  time                movement
789 2014-11-29 09:57:04 1
790 2014-11-29 09:57:10 1
791 2014-11-29 09:57:30 1
792 2014-11-29 09:57:34 1
793 2014-11-29 09:57:40 1
794 2014-11-29 09:57:43 1
795 2014-11-29 09:57:52 1
796 2014-11-29 09:58:09 1
797 2014-11-29 09:58:23 1
798 2014-11-29 09:58:31 1
```

**Result:**

```
time                noise   movement
2014-11-29 9:55:24  6636    null
2014-11-29 9:55:32  5256    null
2014-11-29 9:55:42  5066    null
2014-11-29 9:56:09  11560   null
2014-11-29 9:56:22  5656    null
2014-11-29 9:56:50  7031    null
2014-11-29 9:56:56  5069    null
2014-11-29 9:57:04  null    1
2014-11-29 9:57:06  10088   null
2014-11-29 9:57:10  null    1
2014-11-29 9:57:23  5589    null
2014-11-29 9:57:30  null    1
2014-11-29 9:57:34  null    1
2014-11-29 9:57:40  null    1
2014-11-29 9:57:43  null    1
2014-11-29 9:57:52  null    1
2014-11-29 9:58:09  null    1
2014-11-29 9:58:23  6054    1
2014-11-29 9:58:31  null    1
```

Comment: You need to perform a full outer join, something that is not directly supported on MySQL, but can be easily emulated with the help of a UNION or UNION ALL, as seen here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4796872/full-outer-join-in-mysql

Comment: i used the following, however the result are separated, i.e the time from table A is in a different column to the time from Table B.                  SELECT * FROM noise
LEFT JOIN movement ON noise.time = movement.time
UNION
SELECT * FROM noise 
RIGHT JOIN movement  ON noise.time = movement.time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to perform a `FULL OUTER JOIN` as already commented by Jynus.

```
select t1.time,t1.noise,t2.movement 
from TableA t1 left join TableB t2
on t1.time = t2.time
UNION
select t1.time,t1.noise,t2.movement 
from TableA t1 right join TableB t2
on t1.time = t2.time;
```

Per your last comment: that's correct and it shouldn't since that row is coming from a `RIGHT JOIN` but you can tweak it a bit using `CASE` expression like

```
case when t1.time is null then t2.time else t1.time end as time
```

Or just use `t2.time` in the `RIGHT JOIN` query as pointed by @Karlois

See a demo here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d42d01/2

```
SELECT * FROM
(
select t1.time,t1.noise,t2.movement 
from TableA t1 left join TableB t2
on t1.time = t2.time
UNION
select t2.time,
t1.noise,t2.movement 
from TableA t1 right join TableB t2
on t1.time = t2.time
) tab
ORDER BY time;
```

Comment: Thanks, this partly works, but it does not show the condition: 2014-11-29 9:58:31  null    1 where the noise is null, do you know what i mean

Comment: thanks mate, this works, however it does not show the time where noise = null. i.e.  null null 1

Comment: You don't need `CASE` condition, just use `t2.time` instead of `t1.time` in the second SELECT statement

Comment: Great, very close, we just need to sort the time

Comment: @Ossama, just add a `order by` in the outer query.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to union time of both tables and then create the join with both table to get noise and movment

```
SELECT ts.time, ta.noise, tb.movement 
  FROM (SELECT a.time from tablea a
        UNION
        SELECT b.time from tableb b) ts 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN tablea ta ON ts.time = ta.time
    LEFT OUTER JOIN tableb tb ON ts.time = tb.time
```

Answer (score 0):

I like the `union` and aggregate approach to full outer joins:

```
select time, max(noise) as noise, max(movement) as movement
from ((select a.time, a.noise, NULL as movement
       from tablea a
      ) union all
      (select b.time, NULL, b.movement
       from tableb b
      )
     ) ab
group by time;
```